# Documents not being added to Solr Index from Titan

Tags: solr, titan

I have been trying to create a mixed index on few properties. But the documents are not being added to Solr.

Here is how my setup looks -

Titan 0.5.4  ( tied with Java 7 for now )

Cassandra 2.0.9 ( 2 node cluster)

Solr - 4.8.1 ( 1 node, http mode )

Here is how I am trying to create a mixed index :

```
PropertyKey sharedTxCount = mgmt.makePropertyKey("sharedTxCount").dataType(Integer.class).make();
  TitanGraphIndex sharedTxCountIndex = mgmt.buildIndex("titan", Vertex.class).addKey(sharedTxCount).buildMixedIndex("search");
```

Steps that I followed to create a Solr collection named "titan"

1. Copied the files under TITAN_HOME/conf/solr to Solr machine
2. Created a Solr core called 'titan'
3. Specified 'titan' as the index name while creating mixed index ( as above)

Ran my java app. I do not see any exceptions either in Solr logs or my application 
But no documents are being added to Solr

What is it that I am missing ? ( I know this would be something silly )

My biggest confusion is -
 does Titan need the schema specified in TITAN_HOME/conf/solr  ( I am new to Solr )

I tried adding the field sharedTxCount ( from above) to the schema.xml and commenting out the uniqueID field  - still no documents are being added

I also verified that the Solr core is working fine by adding a document using Solr's REST API

Any help appreciated - have been struggling with this for quite some time now.

My config file -

```
storage.backend=cassandra
storage.cassandra.keyspace=docGraph
storage.batch-loading=true
storage.buffer-size=2000
storage.hostname=bi13.xyz.com,bi14.xyz.com
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
index.search.backend=solr
index.search.solr.mode=http  
index.search.solr.http-urls=http://bi13.xyzcom:8983/solr
```

Comment: I'm trying solr and hbase and facing same issue . @Niks Did you find any fix for the same?

Comment: @hayat Its been quite a while I worked on this.  I don't remember the exact solution but it did work for me with standalone solr instance instead of solr cloud. I remember that record that was being written to solr had a random `document_id` field that was causing the issue. Hope this helps atleast a little.

Comment: I'm trying solr cloud, I'll  try solr standalone hope it works :)